# Need help cleaning up SVG animation

Tags: css, svg, gsap, clip

I have created a demo for an svg fill animation. My approach: I'm creating a mask of the original svg and then clipping that mask. Then I animate the clipped version of the mask from bottom to top on hover. My problem is, that while the animation is happening there is a flicker at the base of the svg element. The flicker is at the very base of the svg and is a very thin line. I tried capturing it on a screenshot but it doesn't get picked up.

Does anyone have an idea how I could clean that up?

Demo: https://codepen.io/aki-sol/pen/JjJLxYG?editors=1100

HTML

```
<svg class="">
  <use xlink:href="#heart"></use>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 -28 512.00002 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill="none" d="m471.382812 44.578125c-26.503906-28.746094-62.871093-44.578125-102.410156-44.578125-29.554687 0-56.621094 9.34375-80.449218 27.769531-12.023438 9.300781-22.917969 20.679688-32.523438 33.960938-9.601562-13.277344-20.5-24.660157-32.527344-33.960938-23.824218-18.425781-50.890625-27.769531-80.445312-27.769531-39.539063 0-75.910156 15.832031-102.414063 44.578125-26.1875 28.410156-40.613281 67.222656-40.613281 109.292969 0 43.300781 16.136719 82.9375 50.78125 124.742187 30.992188 37.394531 75.535156 75.355469 127.117188 119.3125 17.613281 15.011719 37.578124 32.027344 58.308593 50.152344 5.476563 4.796875 12.503907 7.4375 19.792969 7.4375 7.285156 0 14.316406-2.640625 19.785156-7.429687 20.730469-18.128907 40.707032-35.152344 58.328125-50.171876 51.574219-43.949218 96.117188-81.90625 127.109375-119.304687 34.644532-41.800781 50.777344-81.4375 50.777344-124.742187 0-42.066407-14.425781-80.878907-40.617188-109.289063zm0 0" />
  <mask id="clip2">
    <path fill="white" d="m471.382812 44.578125c-26.503906-28.746094-62.871093-44.578125-102.410156-44.578125-29.554687 0-56.621094 9.34375-80.449218 27.769531-12.023438 9.300781-22.917969 20.679688-32.523438 33.960938-9.601562-13.277344-20.5-24.660157-32.527344-33.960938-23.824218-18.425781-50.890625-27.769531-80.445312-27.769531-39.539063 0-75.910156 15.832031-102.414063 44.578125-26.1875 28.410156-40.613281 67.222656-40.613281 109.292969 0 43.300781 16.136719 82.9375 50.78125 124.742187 30.992188 37.394531 75.535156 75.355469 127.117188 119.3125 17.613281 15.011719 37.578124 32.027344 58.308593 50.152344 5.476563 4.796875 12.503907 7.4375 19.792969 7.4375 7.285156 0 14.316406-2.640625 19.785156-7.429687 20.730469-18.128907 40.707032-35.152344 58.328125-50.171876 51.574219-43.949218 96.117188-81.90625 127.109375-119.304687 34.644532-41.800781 50.777344-81.4375 50.777344-124.742187 0-42.066407-14.425781-80.878907-40.617188-109.289063zm0 0" fill="white" />
  </mask>
  <g mask="url('#clip2')">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none">
    </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: black;
}

rect {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  fill: yellow;
  transition: transform 8s ease-in-out;
  will-change: transform;
}

svg:hover rect {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

svg path {
  stroke: yellow;
}

svg {
  width: 300px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate the stroke-dashoffset of a very wide line clipped by the heart. For the stroke you can use again the heart with a use element:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
#line {
  stroke-dasharray:465;
  stroke-dashoffset:465;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out;
}

svg:hover #line {
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
}

svg {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 465" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="clip">
  <path id="heart" fill="none" d="m471.382812 44.578125c-26.503906-28.746094-62.871093-44.578125-102.410156-44.578125-29.554687 0-56.621094 9.34375-80.449218 27.769531-12.023438 9.300781-22.917969 20.679688-32.523438 33.960938-9.601562-13.277344-20.5-24.660157-32.527344-33.960938-23.824218-18.425781-50.890625-27.769531-80.445312-27.769531-39.539063 0-75.910156 15.832031-102.414063 44.578125-26.1875 28.410156-40.613281 67.222656-40.613281 109.292969 0 43.300781 16.136719 82.9375 50.78125 124.742187 30.992188 37.394531 75.535156 75.355469 127.117188 119.3125 17.613281 15.011719 37.578124 32.027344 58.308593 50.152344 5.476563 4.796875 12.503907 7.4375 19.792969 7.4375 7.285156 0 14.316406-2.640625 19.785156-7.429687 20.730469-18.128907 40.707032-35.152344 58.328125-50.171876 51.574219-43.949218 96.117188-81.90625 127.109375-119.304687 34.644532-41.800781 50.777344-81.4375 50.777344-124.742187 0-42.066407-14.425781-80.878907-40.617188-109.289063zm0 0" />
  </clipPath>
  <path id="line" clip-path="url('#clip')" d="M256,465V0" stroke="gold" stroke-width="512"/>
  <use xlink:href="#heart" stroke="gold" ></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: I implemented it in my project and it almost works with my svg (I'm using a slightly more complex svg in my project). If I adapt the code to my svg it get's halfway filled. I think it has to do with the `d` attribute in the `<path id="line">`. Could you clarify what that attribute does? I'm trying to figure out how I can adapt the numbers to fill my svg.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer the path is drawing a very wide `stroke-width="512"` line. For a more  complex shape you may need a different path that is following the shape.  To understand better what is happening in the demo above please change the `stroke-width="512"` to something like 50 or less.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that part of the fill animation. The part I'm struggling with is understanding how this path command attribute `d="M256,465V0"` was generated?

Comment: You begin your path in the point x:256,y;465 i.e the center bottom and then you draw a vertical line toward the point x:the same, y:0

Comment: thank you! It took me a while to wrap my head around it but it makes sense now! I also got it working in my project.